# Is my Zener diode broken?

Tags: diodes, zener

I test my Zener diode IV characteristic (reverse bias).
[image: IV curve]

It is a 1N4728 3.3V Zener diode, but its exponential IV curve seems like a normal diode with lower I_sat(?)
[image: From its datasheet]

Answer (score 17):

No, this Zener diode is not broken, it behaves exactly as expected. Low-voltage Zeners have very soft "knees"; that is, they transition slowly to the conducting state as you increase the voltage, which means that they pass a significant amount of current below their rated Zener voltage. Zeners with higher breakdown voltage have sharper knees.

[image: Zener characteristics vs. breakdown voltage]

[Image source](https://skillbank.co.uk/psu/vr1.htm)

Physically, this is caused by two competing breakdown mechanisms in the Zener diode: The [Zener effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_effect), which is based on tunneling, and the [Avalanche breakdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_breakdown), which is caused by impact ionization. Tunneling is a stochastic process, which means that the Zener effect has a slow onset (the higher the voltage, the more likely it becomes for an electron to tunnel), leading to a soft knee. Avalanche breakdown on the other hand has a sudden onset with a clearly defined voltage threshold, causing a sharp knee, because the semiconductor material goes into breakdown immediately when a critical electric field strength is reached - similar to a lightning bolt ionizing air.

Comment: @WillisLin Some advice: if you need a sharp knee at a lower voltage, you may want to look into the TLV431. It's functionally a programmable zener diode with a very sharp knee regardless of the voltage it's set to.

Comment: I know. I have some of them. I use them with power NPN to make precise linear voltage regulator. The reason I do the zener test is because of curiosity.

Answer (score 6):

Zener diodes are not that great. They do conduct significant (and sometimes unusable) currents below their so-called threshold voltage and, if you compare your graph against the table that you posted in the question, they match: -

[image]

Comment: *low-voltage* zener diodes are not great; higher voltage ones can have very sharp knees.